# Why does Google Search Console's "Core Web Vitals" say a subset of my pages are all good on Mobile and all bad on Desktop?

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console's "Core Web Vitals" is showing these two graphs.

Notice that the number of "good" URLs in one graph exactly match the number of "bad" URLs in the other.
Each day always has the same number on each graph, so it's not likely a random coincidence.

The reports provide only one example, and it is the same URL in both cases (https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Tables/compose/).
The page is static, with no scripts or forms.

The site has hundreds of other pages (all also static without forms), so what is so special about these reported pages that every one of them would be good in one context and bad in the other?

[image: Graphs of Mobile and Desktop URLs, with the good in Mobile exactly matching the bad in Desktop]

Comment: I think this is answered by your other question, since you tested that URL and saw that Google's page speed tool says the page has CLS on desktop.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be another effect of the same problem.  The page contains a table that starts to get drawn before the entire table is processed, and data near the end can cause the column widths to change, hence the rewrite and the "bad" rating.  But the width of the table forces horizontal scrolling on mobile devices, which means that the rewrite doesn't affect mobile displays.